# How can I convert foreach code to Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I'm trying to read my zip faster to make my foreach loop parallel.

But how can i do that based on this method?

```
          private async Task GetImage()
            {
                try
                {
                    PathToZip();
                    int currentIndex = GetCurrentIndex();
                    Content content = _protocol.contents[currentIndex];
                    string imageName = $"{content.contentid}.jpg";

                    using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(PathToZip()))
                    {
                        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry pictureEntry in archive.Entries)

                        {
                            if (string.Equals(pictureEntry.Name, imageName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            {
                                //for reading the image
                                byte[] buffer;
                                long length = pictureEntry.Length;
                                buffer = new byte[length];
                                pictureEntry.Open().Read(buffer, 0, (int)length);
                                myImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(buffer));

                            }
                        }
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
```

How can i do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Non static classes should be assumed non-threadsafe, unless otherwise documented. As far as I can see,  System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive is not documented as thread safe. So I would not expect it to be safe to access multiple entries concurrently.

Comment: How can i do it then faster? @JonasH

Comment: Ideally, the compression library should already support multi-threaded decompression internally. As far as I can see, ZipArchive is not documented to do this, but there are other libraries that might be faster or allow thread safe access to entities. It might also be possible to open multiple read only, shared, streams, and use one ZipArchive per thread. However, you might be IO-limited, so it is not a guaranteed performance win.

Comment: whitch one would you recommend for faster reading inside a zip ?

Comment: questions regarding software recommendations goes to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ . You will need a benchmark if you want to compare different solutions. Either finding one on the internet and hoping it is good enough, or make on yourself.

Comment: ZipArchiveEntry.Open gives you a stream. Here you are copying the stream into a byte[] array and then back into a (Memory)stream. You should start in optimizing your code before thinking of multithreading your overly complicated code for the task.

Comment: can you give a code example on this? @Ralf

Comment: in the easiest naive case `ImageSource.FromStream(pictureEntry.Open())`. But as i said that's the naive case. For example you should check if you are responsible to dispose the stream you get from Open().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're looking for, but here's how you can accomplish it based on your query. Keep in mind that your logic inside the foreach block must be "paralleled-ready".

```
Paraller.foreach (archive.Entries,(pictureEntry)=>
               {
                            if (string.Equals(pictureEntry.Name, imageName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            {
                                //for reading the image
                                byte[] buffer;
                                long length = pictureEntry.Length;
                                buffer = new byte[length];
                                pictureEntry.Open().Read(buffer, 0, (int)length);
                                myImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(buffer));

                            }
               });
```

You can refer official documentation also - [1]:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: That was what i need thanks!